# promise.then() executing before promise.resolve()

Tags: node.js, mongodb, promise, bluebird, asynccallback

I am using bluebird promise library and trying to fetch data from MongoDb, the issue is .then function of promise is executing before i get data from db. here is my code for fetching data.

```
function getCollection( collectionName ) {

var p = database.listCollections().toArray( function(err, collInfos) {

  if ( err ) return null;

  for (var i =  0; i <= collInfos.length; i++) {
    console.log('getdata');
    if ( collInfos[i].name === collectionName ) {
      return collInfos[i];
    } 

    if ( i === collInfos.length - 1 ) {
      return null;
    }
  }

});

p = Promise.resolve( p ).bind( p ).then( function collection( res ) {
  console.log(res,'res');
  return res;
});

return p; }
```

When this code is executed I get undefine with 'res' and 'getdata' prints afterwards.

Comment: This means that `toArray` does not return a promise, `p` is undefined and  `Promise.resolve` doesn't know what to wait for.

Comment: @Bergi so how can i return promise from `toArray` with my actual response i.e null or collection object?

Comment: [**`toArray()`**](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/api/Cursor.html#toArray) returns a Promise if there is no callback passed.

Comment: Btw, what's `bind(p)` supposed to do?

Answer (score 1):

MongoDB methods do return promises *as long as you don't pass a callback*. Since you did pass one, `p` became `undefined` and `Promise.resolve` didn't know what to wait for. Instead, use

```
function getCollection( collectionName ) {
  return Promise.resolve(database.listCollections().toArray())
  .then(function(collInfos) {
    for (var i =  0; i <= collInfos.length; i++) {
      console.log('getdata');
      if ( collInfos[i].name === collectionName ) {
        return collInfos[i];
      }
    }
    return null;
  }, function(err) {
    return null;
  })
  .then( function collection( res ) {
    console.log(res,'res');
    return res;
  });
}
```